# How to get values from jsp file and send to methods in struts?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, struts

Can I get the value from jsp file which was in table format i.e. with td values.Then i get the td values when clicked and get the same values into the method which is in struts java file. can you please send the sample code. thanks in advance.

Comment: There are thousands of `Struts` tutorials in the web.

Comment: i have problem with struts. can you please send sample code here

Answer (score 0):

The fields in your Jsp should have a "name" attribute. And that corresponding attribute should be a variable in your action class with proper getter and Setter methods.

Refer to the link below
http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-hello-world-example/

Comment: k but i need to get from table td values when click on the <td> tag value get the values